# Want to use the getheight() and getwidth() methods to determine the size of the APPLET'S screen

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

I am getting a trouble to - use the `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods to determine the size of the `applet` screen.

Following are the shared image URL's of my code.

[CheckBoard.java](https://codeshare.io/ArU5G)

[ChessBoar.html](https://codeshare.io/HIkzV)

It would be very great if some one can help.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're calling `getHeight` or `getWidth`? FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: Currently the applet is opening according to the width and height set in .HTML but I don't know where to use get getHeight() and  get width() in .HTML or in applet code.. Can you please tell me where to use these functions and how..and how to use them.? Thanks

Comment: I guess that would depend on what you want to use them for

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to use it in java code of applet.

Comment: Can you help me with.the solution code?

Comment: I don't know, you simply call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` from within the applet context when you need it, I'm not sure what more you're asking